# When I boot Ubuntu, I have to log out and in again for the correct theme to load. How can I stop this?

Tags: themes, 15.10

I am running Ubuntu 15.10. Recently when I log in, the theme is not correct. If I then log out, and in again the correct theme loads. Has anyone else had this, and if so, how can I fix this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I have also realised that if I wait a wile before logging in, this error won't occur, however its annoying having to wait, or log off. 
 Also here is what I have already tried: 
 Changing - `etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop`
 to 
`Exec= bash -c "sleep 2; /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon"` 
 
As well as creating the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$(pgrep gnome-settings-)

while [ -n "$pid" ];
do
  pid=$(pgrep gnome-settings-)
  sleep 0
done

exit 0
```

And editing `etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop` 
 to include the script... 
 `Exec=bash -c '/etc/xdg/autostart/gnomesettingsdaemonfix.sh;/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon'`

Comment: I have also realised that if I wait a wile before logging in, this error won't occur, however its annoying having to wait, or log off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can occur if your computer encounters errors while booting up.  Try booting to the command line (without launching lightdm) and see if any errors appear.  Another option would be to grep your logs.

I encountered the issue you are describing twice.  The first took forever to fix.  Eventually, after booting to the command line, I noticed a series of errors relating to my USB ports (a motherboard issue).  I fixed the problem by turning the computer off and unplugging the power supply for 20 seconds.

The second time was was due to my iphone being plugged into the computer during boot.  I solved the issued by not keeping my iphone connected during boot.

Hope this helps.